# Azure App Service: SMTP Exception Insufficient system storage

Tags: azure-web-app-service, smtpclient

We have an azure app service and all of a sudden we are seeing this error:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Insufficient system storage. The server response was: 4.3.1 Out of memory at System.Net.Mail.SendMailAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailCallback(IAsyncResult result) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at
```

We have placed a ticket into the provider that sends the emails, but they are saying they do not see an issue on their end. Now we are thinking that we have pushed something in the last release that could be causing the issue. Of course, we haven't found anything as of right now.

Just curious if other folks had these issues and what the end result was?

We have also used this code on other app services within Azure, but those are controlled by different customers (different instances). The one that is having the issue now is a new customer that we've pushed our code to a week ago Monday. It seemed last week everything was fine though.

Here is our SMTP code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Send an email via code. All email's with attachments are sent through code.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="email">Email Data</param>
/// <param name="smtpServer">The SMTP server.</param>
/// <returns>
/// Task
/// </returns>
private async Task SendSMTPEmail(EmailDTO email, SMTPServerDTO smtpServer)
{
    SmtpClient smtp = null;

    if (email == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email));
    }

    if (smtpServer == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(smtpServer));
    }

    if (!smtpServer.Port.HasValue)
    {
        smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpServer.HostName);
    }
    else
    {
        smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpServer.HostName, smtpServer.Port.Value);
    }

    // Sets the NetworkCredential if a user name and password is required
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(smtpServer.Username) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(smtpServer.Password))
    {
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpServer.Username, smtpServer.Password);
    }

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress(email.FromAddress)
    };

    foreach (string toAddress in email.ToAddresses)
    {
        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
    }

    foreach (string ccAddress in email.CCAddresses)
    {
        mailMessage.CC.Add(ccAddress);
    }

    foreach (string bccAddress in email.BCCAddresses)
    {
        mailMessage.Bcc.Add(bccAddress);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email.ReplyToAddress))
    {
        mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(email.ReplyToAddress);
    }

    mailMessage.Subject = email.Subject;

    mailMessage.Body = email.Body;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email.Importance))
    {
        email.Importance = email.Importance.ToLower();
    }

    switch (email.Importance)
    {
        case "low":
            mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Low;
            break;
        case "normal":
            mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            break;
        case "high":
            mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            break;
        default:
            mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            break;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email.Sensitivity))
    {
        mailMessage.Headers.Add("Sensitivity", email.Sensitivity);
    }
    else
    {
        mailMessage.Headers.Add("Sensitivity", EmailSensitivityConstants.CompanyConfidential);
    }

    foreach (EmailAttachmentDTO emailAttachment in email.Attachments)
    {
        byte[] attachmentData = Convert.FromBase64String(emailAttachment.FileData);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(attachmentData);

        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(memoryStream, emailAttachment.FileName);

        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    }

    await smtp.SendMailAsync(mailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the 3rd party provider of the email service within our Azure instance. This was causing the out of memory issues on our app service etc.

Never heard back on what they did to fix the issue.

Emails are now sending like they should.